# ScrollViewer not updating its ScrollToVerticalOffset on event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a WPF application with a TreeView and a ScrollViewer wrapped around it. I have the treeview working perfectly and I can see the scrollbar showing up when I am expanding the tree view "branches". However, I am adding a feature where the user can click on a button next to each treeview item and it will toggle the next item in the tree view to selected. I got that part working. I can see the next item selected and is highlighted.

However, the scrollviewer doesn't want to update. I have the treeview set up in my xaml as such:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Focusable="False" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False">
    <TreeView 
             x:Name="treeView_root" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             Margin="20,0,0,0"
             MaxHeight="600" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}"
             TreeViewItem.Selected="treeView_Selected" 
             Background="Transparent"
             BorderBrush="Transparent"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
</ScrollViewer>

// In my code behind
private void treeView_Selected(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        TreeViewItem tvi = GetTreeViewItem(treeView_root, treeView_root.SelectedItem);
            
        // Figure out a relative position of the selected node to the scrollviewer
        Point relativePosition = tvi.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), myScrollViewer);
        tvi.BringIntoView();
        myScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
        myScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(relativePosition.Y); // the value of relativePosition is changing with every selected item changing
}
```

Comment: It is unclear why you want to put a TreeView in a ScrollViewer at all. The default TreeView ControlTemplate already contains a ScrollViewer.

Comment: @Clemens I didn't know that. What would be the code then to access the scrollviewer of the treeview in order to update its Y Offset to follow the active/selected treeviewItem?

Comment: BringIntoView should do that.

Comment: @Clemens just calling the tree view item's BringIntoView instead of getting relative psoition, then calling updateLayout and scroll to vertical offset?

Comment: Yes, only BrinIntoView on the relevant TreeViewItem..

Comment: @BionicCode that fixed it for me thank you.